# How can i add organization Legal name to search?

Tags: webform-civicrm, search

I am looking for a way to add Legal name to search. I can see on this [page](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1) that it is possible to add Nickname to search, which i have done.

Civi webform adds great functionality to add relationship to individual contacts. I allow users to lookup their current employer when completing a webform online and with possibility to add new employer.

I'm looking for a way to reduce the amount of duplicate employers added by users because some new organizations added are already in the database but entered different or only with an acronym.

I have turned off wildcard search, and also enabled Nickname field search.

The problem here is that, i have organizations in different languages, so Organization name field is for English name, Nickname is for another language or for acronym. 
I want to be able to also use the Legal name and add it to search. For example: Organization name: **World Bank**, Nikcname: **WB**, Legal name: **The World bank**. This way user will be able to find the same organization by keying it in 3 different ways thus reducing the number of duplicates in the system. 
With only the organization name and Nickname, another user will add 'The World Bank' as new organization.

Answer (score 1):

How are you letting the users lookup their employer?  Is that an autocomplete existing user on the webform?

If so, you can customise what information is displayed in the autocomplete, but that does not currently include legal name.  I'd guess that is a trivial enhancement.

If you want the option of the autocomplete searching on legal name, that might be a bit more effort.  For both, you could raise an issue at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform_civicrm

To add an option for legal name search in the normal search would need a core change following the same pattern as nickname.

A different approach would be to provide a separate lookup facility on legal name using a view but that is not as integrated.

Comment: Yes,  users lookup current employer using autocomplete

Comment: Yes,  users lookup current employer using autocomplete existing user  on webform and current employer of contact 1 is set to contact 2. I don't know how easy it can be to add the legal name to the search preferences as nickname is added here /admin/setting/search?reset=1